# How to parse JSON with dynamic variables in C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I've tried multiple ways of doing this and can't seem to find the proper solution.  The JSON I am trying to parse looks like this

```
{
  "data":
  {
      "random1":
      {
          "language": "en",
          "state": "fl"
      },
      "completelyrandom":
      {
          "language": "fr",
          "state": "wa"
      }
   }
}
```

Currently I am using the below JSON.NET to deserialize into a dynamic object, which gives me access to "language", "state" but I don't know what the parent object is.

```
var jsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer();
dynamic value = jsonSerializer.Deserialize(new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(json)));

foreach (var obj in value.data)
{
    var myObj = obj.First;
    string language = myObj.language;
}
```

How do I get access to "random1" and "completelyrandom"

Comment: why do you want to map it to a dynamic object? - Why not represent it with a real object the deserializer can map to?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, writing all of it out cleared my head.  obj.Name gives my the container.